# Замена содержимого списка Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки

Я не так давно начал изучать python и столкнулся с проблемой которую не могу решить. У меня есть 2 списка в каждом по 33 элемента и пользователь может ввести текст и программа должна пройтись по всех элементах первого списка и изменить элементы. Например: ( Берем например по 3 элемента

```
vvod = input("Введите текст: ")
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = ["1","2","3"]
```

и если ввести abc вывод должен быть 123.
Вроде-бы простая задача и не могу решить, решил уже зарегистрироваться у вас ;D

Спасибо за ответы буду разбираться.

Comment: А если ввести "d e f g" ?

Comment: @Даниил креативный профиль у вас )

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч а я думал никто это не читает )

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = ["1","2","3"]
otvet = []

vvod = input("Введите текст: ")

for c in vvod:
    if c in list1:
       i = list1.index(c)
        otvet.append(list2[i])

print("".join(otvet))
```

Для каждого символа `c` из `vvod` вы тестируете, если он в списке `list1` и затем узнаете его индекс `i` с помощью метода `.index()`.

Символ с тем самым индексом, но теперь из списка `list2`, добавите в результатный список `otvet` методом `.append()`.

В конце концов трансформируете *список* `otvet` на *строку* использованием метода `.join()` на *пустую строку* (отделитель элементов) `""`.

Comment: вы не заменяете содержимое `list1`: *"программа должна пройтись по всех элементах первого списка и изменить элементы"*

Comment: @jfs, вряд ли автор имел в виду, что нужно менять сам список. Судя по тому, что автор пишет дальше, ему действительно нужно просто получить результат маппинга.

Comment: @Александр: заголовок: *"Замена содержимого списка Python"* Текст вопроса: *"программа должна пройтись по всех элементах первого списка и изменить элементы"* -- это **буквальная цитата**.

Comment: @Александр мета-замечание: минус не ставил. Когда я вижу чересчур простой вопрос на SO. Я думаю, а уместны ли вообще подобные вопросы. Потом я вижу два ответа, которые не отвечают на вопрос. Это говорит, что подобные вопросы не слишком просты и уместны.

Answer (score 1):

Можно заменить каждый элемент в списке, если он присутствует во вводе:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = ["1","2","3"]
text = input("Input letters: ")
for i, char in enumerate(list1):
    if char in text:
       list1[i] = list2[i]

print(*list1) # -> 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

UPD: Сначала не заметил уточнения про несколько символов за раз.

Вот исправленный вариант:

```
vvod = input("Введите текст: ")
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = ["1","2","3"]

inp_map = dict(zip(list1, list2))

mapping = lambda line: ''.join(inp_map[s] for s in line)

print(mapping(vvod))
```

Здесь в строчке `inp_map = dict(zip(list1, list2))` создаётся из двух списков вот такой словарь:

```
inp_map = {
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2',
    'c': '3'
}
```

В следующей строчке создаётся лямба-функция, которая принимает на вход строку и с помощью генераторного выражения разбивает её на буквы, каждую букву использует как ключ словаря inp_map и благодаря этому получает соответствующий символ второго списка. После чего с помощью метода join все эти символы обратно склеиваются вместе.

Ну и в последней строке просто применяется эта лямбда-функция применяется к введённому значению.

Comment: допишите решение)) оно работает только для односимвольного ввода. при вводе 'abc' даст ошибку

Comment: Всё как и должно быть, но  не могу разобраться в коде. И меня не забанили в гугле просто не нашел.. Можете написать этот же код только  с очень подробными комментариями? Я с подобным кодом еще не сталкивался прошу не кидаться камнями, что это очень просто)

Comment: Дописал в ответ объяснение того, что там происходит.

Comment: Спасибо буду разбираться!